# PHP too many variables to write

Tags: php, variables

I have the following codes:

```
require("class.XMLHttpRequest.php");
function hot($news){
    $url="https://localhost/search.aspx?search=".$news.""; 
 $ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
 $ajax->setRequestHeader("Cookie","Cookie: host");
 $ajax->open("GET",$url,true);
 $ajax->send(null);
 if($ajax->status==200){
  $rHeader=$ajax->getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
  if(substr_count($rHeader, "Present!")>0) { return true; }
 }else{ return false; }
} 

$content1= hot("britney") ? "britney found" : "";
$content2= hot("gaga") ? "gaga found" : "";
$content3= hot("carol") ? "carol found" : ""; 

$filename = 'result.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
fwrite($handle, "$Content1\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "$Content2\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "$Content3\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "$Content4\r\n");
fclose($handle);
```

i want to shorten the script cuz i have a lot of $ContentN variables
maybe something like foreach ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$celebrities = array('britney','gaga','carol');
$filename = 'result.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'a');

foreach($celebrities as $celebrity)
{
    if(hot($celebrity)) { fwrite($handle, "{$celebrity}\r\n"); }
}

fclose($handle);
```

If you need more celebrities, just add them to the array.

Comment: i have blank spaces in both cases

Comment: Yes, sorry. But in his case it is easier to test.
`if(hot($celebrity)) fwrite($handle, "{$celebrity} found\r\n");` No blank spaces anymore.

Comment: If you don't want blank lines, it's even easier... updated my answer. (Thanks Loïc)

Comment: i have the celebrity names in a text file each on every line, but that's another topic

Comment: In that case, instead of the array you can loop through the lines of the file. The code won't change much. Good luck!

Comment: i've done it with $handle = @fopen('array.txt', "r"); 
if ($handle) { 
   while (!feof($handle)) { 
       $celebrities[] = fgets($handle, 4096); 
   } 
   fclose($handle); 
}

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would be very close to your actual code, but might not be recomanded

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 4 ; $i++)
 fwrite($handle, "${Content$i}\r\n");
```

It is using variable variables : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Not the best solution here : why don't you simply use an array ?

```
$content[1]= hot("britney") ? "britney found" : "";
$content[2]= hot("gaga") ? "gaga found" : "";
$content[3]= hot("carol") ? "carol found" : ""; 
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 4 ; $i++)
 fwrite($handle, $Content[$i]."\r\n");
```

Or ever better, use the solution of *captaintokyo* , because you might not want empty lines in your text file.

Comment: -1 for suggesting variable variables
+2 for suggesting an array

Comment: That's why I was suggesting him to use an array. Variable variables exists and the resulting is closer to his code that using arrays : I first try to be as close as possible to his code and then I suggest arrays which are the good way to to it here.

Comment: I don't like this, cause you still have to write a line for each 'celebrity'.

Comment: @captaintokyo : agreed, I've modified the answer to point to yours

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brief code refactoring for you. Updated variable names, trending topics held in an array, and the foreach you asked about. Code is untested.

```
require("class.XMLHttpRequest.php");

$result_filename = 'result.txt';

$hot_topics = array(
  'britney',
  'gaga',
  'carol'
  );

$handle = @fopen($result_filename, 'a+');
if (!$handle) {
  exit("Unable to open $result_filename");
}

foreach($hot_topics as $topic) {
  if (is_hot($topic)) {
    fwrite($handle, "$topic found\r\n");
  }
}

fclose($handle);

exit("\ncomplete");

function is_hot($news) {
  $url = "https://localhost/search.aspx?search=".$news; 

  $ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  $ajax->setRequestHeader("Cookie", "Cookie: host");
  $ajax->open("GET", $url, true);
  $ajax->send(null);

  if ($ajax->status == 200) {
    $rHeader = $ajax->getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
    if (substr_count($rHeader, "Present!") > 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a print $topic statement inside the foreach loop, first before the if(is_hot()) and then inside that conditional to make sure it's working correctly. After that, try adding a print $rHeader to the is_hot() function. This will let you see the information returned. Is there a chance that it's not writing anything to the file because nothing is currently 'hot'?